# How can I get full path of each node in xml file?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am using xpath for traversal of xml file.I want to know if there is an easy way to get path of each node in the file.One approach that I can think of is to collect all the nodes in an array.Then pass it to a function which takes each node as the argument and keeps on finding parents until document root is reached.So,

```
            function getPathForNode(eachXmlNode, path) {
                if ( eachXmlNode == rootNode ) {
                    return path;
                } else {
                    getPathForNode(eachXmlNode->parent, path+path_of_parent);
                }
            }
```

Please let me know if there is any other better approach or if the recursive function is correct or not?

Comment: *approach or if the recursive function* is correct

Comment: you mean the approach is correct?

Comment: I was wondering if we could use ancestors property of xpath to accomplish this in easier manner.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the host and XPath language version you use.

The easiest way is to use XPath 3 which has the `path` function:

```
//node()/path()
```

Or, if you do not want namespaces in the path, something like:

```
//node()/replace(path(), "Q[{][^}]*[}]", "")
```

XPath 2 solution using `ancestor-or-self::*` and `string-join`:

```
for $node in //node()
return concat( "/",
  string-join(
    for $a in $node/ancestor-or-self::*, 
        $name in node-name($a)
    return concat($name, "[",  $a/../node()[node-name(.) = $name]/(if (. is $a) then position() else ()), "]")
  , "/"),
  if ($node/self::text()) then concat("/text()[",$node/../text()/(if (. is $node) then position() else ()),"]") else ()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @BeniBela doesn't account for attributes. Here's an XPath 2.0 solution that also shows attributes (e.g. /a/b/@c) if present - i.e. it gives you the absolute XPath for a given node:

```xml
concat
(
    '/',
    string-join
    (
        for $n in /your-context-node/ancestor-or-self::node()[position() lt last()],
            $pos in count($n/preceding-sibling::*[name() = $n/name()]) + 1
        return
            concat
            (
                if ($n[self::attribute()]) then '@' else (),
                name($n),
                if ($pos gt 1) then (concat('[', $pos, ']')) else ()
            ),
        '/'
    )
)
```

It omits position if it is one (so a[1]/b[1]/@c is avoided).

To get the absolute path for a given node, `/your-context-node` needs to be replaced with said node.